# Как оставить кнопку активной, при её нажатии

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery

делаю сайт одежды и вот возникла проблема. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог интуитивно понять на какой они из вкладок сайта находится посредством подсвечивания названия той страницы, которая сейчас загружена. Пробовал делать через $_SESSION но это очень муторно, подскажите может есть более простой способ, например, через js? Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: привидите пример кода, конткретно этих кнопок.

Comment: А в чем проблема в разметке каждой страницы подсветить нужную кнопку? Или написать скрипт, который по каким-либо параметрам будет идентифицировать страницу и подсвечивать соответствующую ей кнопку?

Comment: не знаю как там по Best Practices, я бы навесил на кнопки `id` соответствующие секции в `url`, т.е. `<a href="" id="boots">`, в `$(function(){});` на js разбирается url (`window.location.pathname`), например `site.com/cat/boots`, получаем текущий раздел boots из url, добавляем элементу с `id="boots"` класс `active` (`$("#boots").addClass("active")`) и т.д.

Comment: <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item right-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="..\pages\woman.php">Женское<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item right-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="..\pages\man.php">Мужское<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

Мне всего лишь нужно привязать активность вот к этим двум ссылкам и всё